# raising an exception when i click my button

Tags: delphi

im trying to raise an exception for my button,i have 2 buttons on my form button one starts a test and button 2 shows the results of a test,when i click button 2 which shows the results without starting a test an exception message appears but i do not want it to show the break cancel or continue options i just want it to show a message like error,i have been trying to raise an exception for my button but it seems i am failing

this is the button where i want to raise an exception

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    form3.Show;

end;
```

Comment: Apparently, the name of 'button 2' is `Button3`. May I suggest `btnShowResults` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I woudn't raise an exception, I'd simply display an error message. The *first lines* of the second button's click handler should be

```
if not FTestHasBeenRun then
begin
  MessageBox(Handle, 'No test has been run.', PChar(Caption), MB_ICONERROR);
  Exit;
end;

// Display test results here.
```

Needless to say, `FTestHasBeenRun` is a variable with default value `false` that is set to `true` as soon a test has been completed.

It might even make sense to display a more gentle informational message, instead:

```
MessageBox(Handle, 'No test has been run.', PChar(Caption), MB_ICONINFORMATION);
```

In addition, I'd make the second button disabled until a test has been run.

If you prefer an exception, you can raise one manually by writing

```
raise Exception.Create('No test has been run.');
```

Then you might get the Delphi debugger popping up. But! That only happens when you run your application from within the Delphi IDE. If you start your program by double-clicking the EXE in Windows Explorer, you will get an ordinary error message box. You can write your own exception-handling code if you want to present the message in a user-friendly manner (not talking about 'exceptions' etc.).

However, from your comments it appears that you do **not** want to raise an exception (or show an error message) manually. You want to suppress one that is being raised somewhere else. The solution is to do as in my first code snippet, or to disable the second button until a test has been run. This way the user will not be able to give the 'analyse data' command before there is any data to analyse.

Comment: so im trying to do this procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    form3.Show;
     MessageBox(Handle, 'No test has been run.', PChar(Caption), MB_ICONINFORMATION);
end; but still the other exception message is popping up,i do not want it to pop up i just want the message No test has been run to pop up

Comment: @joe like: The first lines of the terribly-named `Button3Click` procedure should be `if not FTestHasBeen...` as I wrote above. The `Exit` makes sure that the rest of the procedure is skiped. And so the part trying to analyse null data is skipped, and so you probably will not get the exception. [It seems like you start analyse in the `FormShow` event of your `Form3` (also terribly-named).] Of course, it is up to you to set the flag `FTestHasBeenRun` to `true` after the test has been run - the default value needs to be `false`.

Comment: What's wrong with raising an exception? The advantage of that is that you let somebody else decide how to handle it. Which allows a GUI program to turn it into a message box, and a headless DLL to turn it into an error code.

Comment: @David: Very good point. I updated the answer as to be less 'anti-exception'.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand ok im just a newbie an im getting confused how can i disable the button so that the user does not analyse data before running the test?

Comment: In the IDE, set the button's `Enabled` property to `false`. Then, when the test is completed, do `btnShowResults.Enabled := true` (or, with your less thought-out control names, `Button3.Enabled := true`).

Answer (score 3):

> I do not want it to show the break cancel or continue options

That's not something that you change in code. You need to change your debugger options to effect that change.

You can stop all exceptions from provoking the break/continue dialog by unchecking the *Notify on language exceptions* option on the *Language Exceptions* page of the debugger options dialog.

Or if you want to be a bit cuter, you can choose to ignore certain classes of exception. Again, from the *Language Exceptions* page of the debugger options dialog, add your exception classes to the list. Or, on the break/continue dialog, check the *Ignore this exception type* and press continue. When you have asked for an exception type to be ignore, you'll no longer see the break/continue dialog for that exception class, or its subclasses.

---

> I'm trying to raise an exception for my button

Well, not in the code that you showed. If you want to raise an exception, well, you can simply do that:

```
raise SomeExceptionClass.Create(...);
```

Or, if you want to show a message box, do so.

---

I suspect that you are trying to show this code

```
form3.Show;
```

from running when it is going to raise an exception. There are a few ways that you can do that:

1. Disable the button that has the call to `form3.Show` behind it, if you know it is going to raise an exception.
2. Don't call `form3.Show` if you know it is going to raise an exception.
3. Let `form3.Show` be called, but detect the error condition, show an error dialog, and then call `Abort`. You'd have to do this in code that runs before the form actually shows, so perhaps you could add a method to the form that would call `Show` only if the form was in a state to show. This would allow you to move the decision closer to the code that knows about the reason behind the decision.

---

Finally, your variables, types and methods can all be given names. You must start doing so because it's hopeless trying to program with entities that are numbered rather than named. What's more, you should stop using the global variables containing references to forms that the IDE provides for you. I wish the IDE would stop doing that because it's a terrible practice. Create instances when you need them, and don't use global variables where they are not appropriate.

Comment: This is probably true, but I don't think it what the OP needs to do. He needs know if there is some data to analyse or not.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I read the comment to your answer, "but still the other exception message is popping up, i do not want it to pop up i just want the message", and from the question "i do not want it to show the break cancel or continue options i just want it to show a message like error". So my understanding is that the code is already raising an exception. There's no need to raise another one.

Comment: Yes, I agree. The text of the Q contradicts the title, which is about manually showing an error message/raising an exception. Still, I do believe the right thing to do is to *not* try to analyse any data before a test has been run. So you either disable the button before a test has been run, or you do as in my first code snippet (or both).